# NOT RECIEVING The Datas on GET Method - MVC WEB API

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I got a problem that my asp.net mvc solution isn't reading my json, and I need some help with this.
First of all, let me introduce you guys to the problem.
I need just to put a GET METHOD, read some information and that's all.
But, the problem is, when i am using a simple j-son it works. As you guys can see above:
.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/vzTAM.jpg "The Postman"
.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/qwt8d.jpg "The View showing the data"
.
Here what I'm using on my controller/mycodes

https://i.stack.imgur.com/jgUKa.jpg "The Code"
.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/PmnhM.jpg "The Code2"
.
And here what i really need to receive, but comes null:
.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/h4Ahx.jpg "The J-Son"
.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/iG9Ej.jpg "Returns null"

-- FindAll Clients:

```
public class ProductClient
    {
        private string BASE_URL = "http://localhost:50166/api/Clientes";


        public IEnumerable<Cliente> findAll()
        {
            try
            {
                HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
                client.BaseAddress = new Uri(BASE_URL);
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

                HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync(BASE_URL).Result;

                if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    return response.Content.ReadAsAsync<IEnumerable<Cliente>>().Result;
                }
                return null;
            }
            catch
            {
                return null;
            }
        }
    }
```

My Index

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    ProductClient pc = new ProductClient();
    ViewBag.Clientes = pc.findAll();
    return View();
}
```

Comment: this is a must read for newcomers and it helps you get an answer https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Please include the code to the post

Comment: Done. I got the code to the post.

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify [FromUri] in the method's parameter. Web API expecting it to come from the Request body by default. You can add the [FromUri] like this:

```cs
public IEnumerable<string> findAll([FromUri]List<string> stringColumnNames)
{
   return Ok(pc.findAll(stringColumnNames));
}
```

add call like this

```cs
http://localhost:59511/api/Values?str[]="abc"&str[]="xyz"
```